# String comparison in preprocessor conditions in C

Tags: c, macros

I am passing a compiler option in makefile called `DPATH`, which is something like `DPATH=/path/to/somefile`. Based on this, I have to write a macro such that:-

```
#if "$(DPATH)"=="/path/to/x"
#error no x allowed
#endif
```

How do I compare `DPATH` with the string in a preprocessor conditional test?

Comment: why is it something you want to check in the C code? I'd put it in the makefile.

Comment: ah because I am using some other macros defined here and there too in my condition, so it is actually `if $DPATH && some1==3 && some2==7 &&env_defined==3.0`

Comment: That just doesn't sound right... I think your configuration management requires some more thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in the preprocessor. `#if` can only evaluate integer expressions making no reference to functions or variables.  All identifiers that survive macro expansion are replaced by zeroes, and a string constant triggers an automatic syntax error.

Without knowing more about your problem, I would suggest writing a tiny test program that is compiled *and executed* during the build, and Makefile goo to fail the build if the test doesn't pass.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
   if (!strcmp(DPATH, "/path/to/x") || some1 == 3 || some2 == 7 || ...)
   {
       fputs("bogus configuration\n", stderr);
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

and then

```
all : validate_configuration
validate_configuration: config_validator
    if ./config_validator; then touch validate_configuration; else exit 1; fi
config_validator: config_validator.c
    # etc
```